# Am I allowed to make circular references with constants structs?

Tags: c, struct, circular-reference

Am I allowed to do this in [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)?

```
typedef struct dlNode {
    dlNode* next, prev;
    void* datum;
} dlNode;

const static dlNode head={
    .next = &tail,
    .prev = NULL,
    .datum = NULL
};

const static dlNode tail={
    .next = NULL,
    .prev = &head,
    .datum = NULL
};
```

I can make my program work without this. It'd just be convenient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can. You just have to forward declare `tail` to get it to work:

```
typedef struct dlNode {
    struct dlNode* next;
    struct dlNode* prev;
    void* datum;
} dlNode;

const static dlNode tail;

const static dlNode head={
    .next = &tail,
    .prev = NULL,
    .datum = NULL
};

const static dlNode tail={
    .next = NULL,
    .prev = &head,
    .datum = NULL
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that you could (effectively) prototype variables & structs.

Comment: Note that this is called "tentative definitions" and does not work in C++.

Comment: @o11c That pattern is easily replaceable by a class.

Comment: @bunyaCloven doesn't mean it's not worth mentioning that tentative definitions specifically don't work in C++

Comment: Specifically, in C++, slapping a `class foo{ } foo_instance;` around head/tail (and removing `static`) will get it to compile to read-only data in static storage, even without optimization.  https://godbolt.org/g/T9Mavc.

Comment: Ooh, I never managed to get any way to work, I ended up making it `extern`. Adding an artificial class never occurred to me, I wouldn't call it "easy".

Answer (score 5):

You are absolutely allowed to do it: add a forward declaration of `tail`, and C will merge it with a later definition:

```
typedef struct dlNode {
    const struct dlNode* next, *prev;
    void* datum;
} dlNode;

const static dlNode tail; // <<== C treats this as a forward declaration

const static dlNode head={
    .next=&tail,
    .prev=NULL,
    .datum=NULL
};

const static dlNode tail={ // This becomes the actual definition
    .next=NULL,
    .prev=&head,
    .datum=NULL
};
```

Note that you should fix your `struct` declaration to make `next` and `prev` constant, otherwise your definition would discard constant qualifiers.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/jBeGP9)